# Python - List function inserting values invalid syntax

Tags: python, list

I am new here learning Python. I have a problem of syntax but I am unable to fix it. Can someone please help ?

Here's the code:

```
def saisie(the_list)
input_string = input("Enter a list elements separated by space (max 6)\n")

the_list = input_string.split()

if len(the_list) > 6:
    return '{}Error'

return '{}Error'    
else:
    return f'user list: {the_list}'

saisie(liste)
```

and I got this error :

```
  File "c:/Users/Jay/Desktop/Python Exercices/app/tribulle.py", line 6
    def saisie(the_list)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Which is the invalid syntax, what should I change please?

Answer (score 2):

When defining a function, you must put a colon at the end of the "def saisie(the_list)" or else Python will not know that you are defining a function.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the colon, it should be

```
def saisie(the_list):
```